# How do I trigger trade when price touches the channel?

Tags: pine-script

I'm new to pine and I'm trying to trigger a long trade when prices touch the upper band of the Donchian Channel and vice versa.

Currently, based on my current code, I can see that prices have touched the upper band but it did not trigger a long trade until much later (refer to image).

[image: chart]

I've tried to decrease the Donchian period (from a default of 20) but it still doesn't trigger a signal.

Here's the code that I used:

```
length = input(20, minval=1)
lower = lowest(length)
upper = highest(length)
basis = avg(upper, lower)

// 4. Long trading conditions
enterLong = upTrend and (close >= upper) or (high >= upper) 
exitLong = (low <= lower) or (close <= basis)

// 5. Short trading conditions
enterShort = downTrend and (close <= lower) or (low <= lower)
exitShort = (high >= upper) or (close >= basis)

// 6. Submit entry orders
if (enterLong)
    strategy.entry(id="OL", long=true, qty=posSize)

if (enterShort)
    strategy.entry(id="OS", long=false, qty=posSize)

// 7. Submit exit orders
strategy.close(id="OL", when=exitLong)
strategy.close(id="OS", when=exitShort)
```

Is there a way that I can improve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you get the upTrend and downTrade values? How do you enter a trade?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your logic:

```py
enterLong = upTrend and (close >= upper) or (high >= upper)
```

evaluates to `false` if `upTrend and close < upper or high >= upper`

change it to

```py
enterLong = upTrend and high >= upper
enterShort = downTrend and low <= lower
```

Comment: I meant how to trigger trade, apologies for the unclear title. I've rephrased the question from "enter trade" to "trigger trade" and added my entry and exit codes above.

Comment: Do you mean how to trigger alerts when condition met? please not in strategy version you cannot generate alerts. Only in the study version the alerts can be generated . Use the alertcondition() pine script built in function.

Comment: @MarxBabu not alerts, but to enter the trade. I've been trying to code it in such a way that as long as the candle touches the upper channel, it will enter a long trade. But based on the image I posted on top, the first candle that touched the channel is a bearish spinning top (4th candle from the left) but the trade only got triggered much later (bearish spinning top in the uptrend with the blue arrow that says "OL" which stands for open long.

Comment: @jaithomas so there must be something wrong with your `enterLong` logic. Can you update the question to include the definitions for `upper` and `lower` variables ? Also have you made sure that it actually touches and doesn't turn away 1 points near the channel bounds ?

Comment: If you use Strategy only in the close of the BAR the condition is executed .Check are you using Study() or Strategy()

Comment: I believe you can't use strategy.entry with a `study()`, at least in version 3 you can't. @MarxBabu

Comment: @MarxBabu I'm using strategy()

Comment: @reportgunner right, sorry! Really new to this. Just updated my question with the codes for upper and lower variables. I'm not sure about your second question/ how to make sure, I just assumed that for the candle to touch the channel, it must have either closed above the channel or have it's high above the channel

Comment: @jaithomas If you use strategy() the calculation is not realtime ,only when the new bar opens the logic calc will happen based on the previous close.  use this two line and test //@version=3    study("Test", overlay=true, shorttitle="TestCalc") ,enable a chat i can help you

Comment: @MarxBabu your help would be much appreciated! But I can't seem to open a chat here

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to go Long when price closes ABOVE the Channel, because if it's "touching" the channel, maybe we'll reverse.

You have to use strategy.close() to exit long at market price when low touches the channel.

On Donchian Channels usually you have the 20days for the Upper Channel, and 10days for Lower Channel to Exit.

This is what I do in Pine Script v5, adjust it to your code:

```
// Inputs
i_wideLength = input(20)
i_shortLength = input(10)

// Donchian Channels
upperBand = ta.highest(high, i_wideLength)[1]
upperLowerBand = ta.lowest(low, i_shortLength)

// Signals
longSignal = ta.crossover(close, upperBand)
exitLong = low <= upperLowerBand

// Strategy
if longSignal
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

if exitLong
    strategy.close(id="Long")
```

I think the code you need it's just this line:

```
exitLong = low <= upperLowerBand
```

Let me know if you need anything else.